# Long delay sending Emails

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-mvc-5

In our internal ERP application, F&A collegue's can approve a timesheets for developers at the end of the month. After clicking 'approve' there is a abnormal long delay. This is not network related as this occurs in my workspace branch, test environment and on the live environment.

There are multiple emails send in this method. How can I speed this process up?

This is the ApproveTimesheetByApprover method as an example:

```
public bool ApproveTimesheetByApprover(int timesheetId, string commentConsultant, string commentAccount, int accountContactId, bool forced = false)
{
    //Get subject timesheet
    var timesheet = _timesheetsQueryHandler.GetById(timesheetId).ReturnValue;

    //Check if this user is in right group to approve this timesheet
    var approverList = _getAllGroupUsersByGroupIdQueryHandler.Execute(timesheet.Project.ApproverId).ReturnValue.Where(gu => !gu.IsDeleted).ToList();
    var approver = approverList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == UserId);
    if (approver != null)
    {
        //Db updates
        var statusCommand = new UpdateTimesheetStatusCommand(timesheetId, "approver", true);
        var statusSuccessUpdate = _timesheetCommandHandler.UpdateStatus(statusCommand);
        if (forced && statusSuccessUpdate)
        {
            var commandCons = new UpdateTimesheetStatusCommand(timesheetId, "consultant", true);
            statusSuccessUpdate = _timesheetCommandHandler.UpdateStatus(commandCons);
        }

        if (statusSuccessUpdate)
        {
            _actionLogic.SetCompleteAction(timesheetId);


            // remove approval action from the list of actions for all relevant users
            List<EmailTemplateActionReferenceDto> emailTemplateActionReferences = _emailActionNotificationLogic.GetEmailTemplateActionReference(EmailTemplates.TimesheetApprovedConsultant);
            foreach (EmailTemplateActionReferenceDto emailTemplateActionReference in emailTemplateActionReferences)
            {
                var actionTypeId = emailTemplateActionReference.ActionTypeId;
                _actionLogic.SetCompleteActionForUsers(actionTypeId, timesheetId);
            }

            //E-mail consultant
            string dateString = timesheet.SubjectDate.ToString("MMMM yyyy", new CultureInfo(_getCultureByIdQuery.Execute(timesheet.User.CultureId).Name));
            SendMailToConsultant_Approve(dateString, commentConsultant, timesheet.UserId);

            //update skilldetails
            _skillDetailsLogic.AutoUpdateSkillsAndProjectConsultantSkillsFromTimesheet(timesheet);

            if (timesheet.Account.SignsTimesheets)
            {
                var accountContactCommand = new UpdateTimesheetAccountContactCommand(timesheetId, accountContactId);
                var accountContactSuccessUpdate =
                    _timesheetCommandHandler.UpdateAccountContact(accountContactCommand);

                Guid approveEmailGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
                _updateTimesheetClientValidationGuidQuery.Execute(timesheet.Id, approveEmailGuid);


                //E-mail account
                if (accountContactSuccessUpdate)
                {
                    var approverContact = _getContactByUserIdQuery.Execute(approver.UserId);
                    var approverName = approverContact.FirstName + " " + approverContact.LastName;
                    var consultantContact = _getContactByUserIdQuery.Execute(timesheet.UserId);
                    var consultantName = consultantContact.FirstName + " " + consultantContact.LastName;
                    var accountContact = _getAccountContactQueryHandler.Execute(accountContactId).ReturnValue;
                    dateString = timesheet.SubjectDate.ToString("MMMM yyyy", new CultureInfo(_getCultureByIdQuery.Execute(accountContact.CultureId).Name));
                    SendMailToAccount(dateString, consultantName, approverName, accountContact, approveEmailGuid,
                        timesheet.Project.ProjectReference, commentAccount);
                }
            }

            return statusSuccessUpdate;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, you've posted quite a lot of code. If that's the code that's taking a long time, have you used any profiling or other diagnostic tools to work out *where* it's taking a long time? Given how much code is there, everyone else would be guessing - but *you* should be able to narrow it down.

Comment: We don't see the code to send emails, but from the looks of the method looks like you need to use async/await, or send the sending off to tasks that you don't want to wait on. Emails take time to get sent because of the smtp (guessing) negotiation, we always offload those to background tasks/threads.

Comment: I indeed needed async/await for my methods. It's my first experience with this, read upon some documentation on how to implement async/await and tried it out. Thanks for the feedback!